# Use Java EE Transaction Annotation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, transactional

Plan is to move away from Spring Transaction towards Java EE transactions

I need to replace annotation (@Transactional)
 org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

WITH

Java EE transaction annotation.

The issue is where I read it tells use EJB but EJB is not needed. Please give me a small example that use Java EE Transaction with out Spring and EJB.

Comment: It is possible to develop an application that uses JPA for persistence and foregoes container-managed transactions for application-managed transactions.  While there are probably some use cases for this, I don't see why you would forego the benefits of container-management.  If you are developing a web application, maybe EJB 3.0 Lite will be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

From Java 1.5 for managing the transactions we have a API which is introduce in extended java package (also called Java Transaction API(JTA)) which a user can implement their own transaction isolation levels.No need of specifiec EJB modules to be introduce here.You can make your own class as Transnational manager by implementing a simple Interface defined by API call **User Transaction**.

Please refer the below Link for details of the usage.
[http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html][1]

Hope this helps! Have a good Code.

Regards,
Jagadish